# JQGrid datatype as Ajax function not getting called

Tags: jqgrid

`JQGrid` datatype as `Ajax` function not getting called. once I tried to debug using firebug, found out that those lines are not executed.

Please let me know the issue with my code.

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    //url:'example.xml',

    datatype: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "example.xml",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "xml",
            mtype: "GET",
            complete: function(jsondata, stat) {
                alert((jsondata.responseText));
                if (stat == "success") {
                    alert("ew");
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error")
            }
        });
    },
    colNames: ['QueueName', 'SLA Associated', 'SLA met', 'SLA Breached', 'SLA MET %', 'SLA Breached %'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'QueueName',
        index: 'QueueName',
        width: 150
    }, {
        name: 'SLAAssociated',
        index: 'SLAAssociated',
        width: 150
    }, {
        name: 'SLAmet',
        index: 'SLAmet',
        width: 150
    }, {
        name: 'SLABreached',
        index: 'SLABreached',
        width: 150
    }, {
        name: 'SLAMETPer',
        index: 'SLAMETPer',
        width: 150
    }, {
        name: 'SLABreachedPer',
        index: 'SLABreachedPer',
        width: 150
    }],
    pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
    rowNum: 1,
    rowList: [5, 10],
    imgpath: 'themes/basic/images'
});
```

---

In Header I add as follows

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/basic/grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/jqModal.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/report.css" />
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Hi Please find my entire HTML Code. is there any issues with this code ? the Ajax function I called in the datatype is not get executed.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: function(postData) {
      $.ajax({ // THis function is not getting called @ any time.
        url: '1234.xml',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: postdata,
        error: function() {
          alert(1);
        },
        complete: function(xmlData, stat) {
          alert(0);
        },

      });

    },
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
    colModel: [{
      name: 'invid',
      index: 'invid',
      width: 55
    }, {
      name: 'invdate',
      index: 'invdate',
      width: 90
    }, {
      name: 'amount',
      index: 'amount',
      width: 80,
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      name: 'tax',
      index: 'tax',
      width: 80,
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      name: 'total',
      index: 'total',
      width: 80,
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      name: 'note',
      index: 'note',
      width: 150,
      sortable: false
    }],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',
    caption: "My first grid"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>jqGrid Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/basic/grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/jqModal.css" />
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<body>
  <table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
  <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

your function needs to take in the postdata as a parameter

```
datatype: function(postData) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "example.xml",
                    data: postData,  
                    dataType: "xml",
                    mtype: "GET",
                    complete: function(jsondata, stat) { alert((jsondata.responseText));
                        if (stat == "success") {
                        alert("ew");
                        }
                    },
                    error : function () {alert("error")}
                });
            },
```

Comment: I have tried to give the relative path for the url. but still issues occur. please help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: why double brackets here `alert((jsondata.responseText));`?
and your missing a semi colon here `error : function () {alert("error")}`

Comment: Please look the below snippet. still the function not get executed.

datatype: function(postData) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "example.xml",
                        data: postData,  
                        dataType: "xml",
   mtype: "GET",
                        complete: function(jsondata, stat) { 
       alert(jsondata.responseText);
                            if (stat == "success") {
    alert("ew");
       }
                        },
   error : function () {
    alert("error");
   }
                    });
                },

Comment: if you required my whole HTML file, i will send you. please let me know. Thanks.